# Windows 7 system freezes: would like to know if they could be related to MrxSmb, Event ID 8003 errors

Tags: windows-7

First, this question centers around a home network. Is it okay to ask here? Or should I go to SuperUser? (I see less answers over there, but I'll go there if that would be more appropriate.)

Network setup:
1 Machine running XP Pro
1 Machine running Win7 Ultimate
Comcast router
Linksys WRT610N Wireless router

The Win7 machine goes into a total, unrecoverable system freeze frequently. I was tearing out my hair trying to ascertain a cause, but I noticed that it usually seems to correspond with performing operations on the shared folders on the XP machine. The last 2 occasions that the Win7 machine froze, I saw this entry for Event ID 8003 from source MrxSmb in the Event log of the XP machine:

> The master browser has received a
>   server announcement from the computer
>   WIN7_COMPUTER that believes that it is
>   the master browser for the domain on
>   transport NetBT_Tcpip_{320B32A7-FED9.
>   The master browser is stopping or an
>   election is being forced.

My question is twofold:

1. Could this cause a Win7 system freeze?
2. If so, what could I configure differently on my network to stop these conflicts over who is the master browser?

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, I doubt the 8003 event is causing the computer to freeze.  I do have a couple of suggestions which may fix the issue.

1. You state that you have both a Comcast router and a Linksys router.  Is it possible that one computer may be getting its address from one of the routers versus the other?  I would check that either a) you have only one router doing DHCP or b) you have both computers set to static addresses and the same gateway.
2. I have had Windows 7 explorer windows freeze during file copies to/from older systems but the rest of the system remain functional.  Turning off remote differential compression, autotuning, and IPv6 (I wasn't using it anyway) on the Windows 7 system has resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Both machines look to the Linksys for DHCP. I don't know how to check the Comcast one to see if it is trying, but that shouldn't make any difference if no machien is actually listening to it -- right? I will try your other suggestions as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I experienced the system freeze twice again this morning, having turned off all of those services. Anyone know of anything else I can investigate? Thanks so much!